# Replacing document with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, preload

so what I'm trying to do is simple to explain: I have one page (let's call it `login.html`) that has a script whenever an `$.get` `$.load` `$.post` is called it shows an progress bar like youtube now my problem is to move to another page with one of this methods so for example I complete the login and it loads the `page2.html` and only shows the `page2.html` and leaves `login.html` after `page2.html` is ready to be displayed

Kind of like a preload, any ideas? I've tried the `$('hmtl').load('page2.html');` but it messes up my CSS and SCRIPTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use ajax loader which basically preloads the specified page and then just switches a body element of current and the preloaded page.

Here is an [example](http://preloaders.net/en/ajax_loader_script)